# Can a transpose of a 2d vector geometrically be interpreted as 90º rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, surfaces

See the (octave) code below.

```
pkg load geometry;

v1 = [3 4 0];
v2 = [2 5 0];
vr = rotateVector(v2, deg2rad(90));
vr = [vr(1) vr(2) 0];

dp = dot(v1, v2);
cp = cross(v1, vr);

disp('Dot p.: '), disp(dp);
disp('Parallelogram surface area: '), disp(cp);
```

This is the output:

```
Dot p.:
    26
Parallelogram surface area:
    0   -0   26
```

Here the cross product represents the surface area of the parallelogram between v1 and the rotated vector v2 by 90 degrees. (3d vectors are used to be able to use the cross product, but the Z in X, Y and Z of the vectors is 0, hence be ignored).

The cross product (or technically the length of this resulting vector) equals the dot product.

This cannot be a coincidence.

So can I conclude  that the transpose in the dot product v1**T**v2 means: rotate vector by 90 degrees, in case of 2d vectors.

(If not, how is this reasoning invalid?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

What you found was that $v_1\cdot v_2 = \Vert v_1 \times v_r\Vert$, where $v_r$ is a 90-degree rotation of $v_2$ in the xy-plane, right? This is expected. We can show it by working out both sides out from their coordinates. Or we can see geometrically that $v_1\cdot v_2 = \cos\theta \Vert v_1 \Vert \Vert v_2 \Vert$, while the area of the parallelogram is $|\sin(\theta+\pi/2)|\Vert v_1 \Vert \Vert v_r \Vert = |\cos\theta|\Vert v_1 \Vert \Vert v_2 \Vert$. So the dot product is $\pm$ the length of the cross product.

However, when we transpose in the expression $v_1\cdot v_2 = v_1^Tv_2$, that is not a rotation of $v_1$. Note how it doesn't say $v_1^T\times v_2$, i.e. it is not a cross product. Rather, it is to be read as a matrix product, where $v_2$ is a column vector, and $v_1^T$ has been changed into a row vector by transposing. It still represents the same vector in space, but is notated differently (horizontally).

Comment: I see now what the dot product represents. This video helped me with it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrDAU2N0FEg Where the dot product is explained as a result of simularity. That is what I was looking for. Thanks for helping me see that what I thought I found was actually nothing.

Comment: That is a good way to think about dot products, and indeed how I think about them. I should say that you were not really wrong though. As you saw, you could interpret the dot product as the area of the parallelogram after rotating one of the vectors is rotated by 90 degrees. You do lose the information in the sign though. That being said, it still has nothing to do with transposing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

Let's consider an example. You have a vector with coordinate x=0, y=2. It means the vector lies on the y axis and has the length of 2 unit. You can present it as a row matrix, namely (0, 2).
Transposing the vector means rewriting it as a column matrix, but coordinates remain unchanged (x=0 and y=2).